# Upload any file with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

**This is not a question**, is something that I just figured out and wish to share. If anyone has a better idea, it is welcome

I am developing a system for quoting furnished offices for rent, to quote, we need to have the elements that make up an office, such as furniture, area, blueprints, some renders, and so on.

So, we need that when defining the area of the office, we could attach it the following images:

- 4 rendered images
- 4 real photographs
- 1 blueprint
- 1 CAD (dxf) file
- 1 Sketchup (skp) file
- 1 SweetHome3D (sh3d) file

We did not have any trouble uploading/processing the images. But the dxf, skp and sh3d files were a real pain.

We got an error reported by ImageMagick, that, telling us that it did not have any delegate for dxf, skp and sh3d files

We solved it with the following code:

```
class ImagenUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  include CarrierWave::Processing::MiniMagick

  permissions 0666
  directory_permissions 0766
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def cache_dir
    'tmp/cache'
  end

  # ** THIS IS PART OF THE SOLUTION (if: :image?) **
  version :i50, if: :image? do
    process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
    process :strip
    process convert: 'jpg'
    process :auto_orient
  end
  version :i800, if: :image? do
    process resize_to_fit: [800, 800]
    process :strip
    process convert: 'jpg'
    process :auto_orient
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w[jpg jpeg gif png pdf dxf skp sh3d]
  end

  def filename
    ( secure_token + File.extname(super).downcase ) if original_filename.present?
  end

  def content_type_whitelist
    [/image\/|application\//]
  end

  def whitelist_mime_type_pattern
    /image\/|application\//
  end

  def content_type_blacklist
    ['application/text', 'application/json']
  end

  def default_url(*args)
    '/images/fallback/'+[version_name,'default.png'].compact.join('_')
  end

  protected

    def secure_token
      var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
      model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
    end

    def image?(new_file)
      tipo_contenido = new_file.content_type
      # **** THIS IS THE REAL SOLUTION ****
      if %w(dxf sh3d skp).include? tipo_contenido.split('.')[1]
        false
      else
        tipo_contenido.start_with? 'image'
      end
    end
end
```

I hope this will be usefull to someone.